# TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tweepy

Running this gives me the error `TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable`

I'm trying to get the statuses from the user.

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import tweepy
import random
import time
import itertools

def paginate(iterable, page_size):
    while True:
        i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
        iterable, page = (itertools.islice(i1, page_size, None),
                list(itertools.islice(i2, page_size)))
        if len(page) == 0:
            break
        yield page

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("removed", "removed")
auth.set_access_token("removed", "removed")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

timeline = api.user_timeline("removed")

for res in paginate(timeline, 50):
    for twet in res[1]:
        print(twet.id)
```

Comment: what is the **full text** of the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fav.py", line 25, in <module>
    for twet in res[1]:
TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a pretty simple fix: Just remove the `[1]` part, and you should get the ID for each tweet.

```
for res in paginate(timeline, 50):
    for twet in res:
        print(twet.id)
```